# Whatsapp not opening

Tags: whatsapp, windows-mobile

I updated whatsapp on my Lumia 620 today and after that I am unable to open whatsapp. Whenever I try to open it, the screen just goes back to the home. I tried restarting my phone and also reinstalling whatsapp but nothing works.